# Snowflake Table from Databricks using Python/Scala

Tags: scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks

I want to create a table and load data into it in Snowflake from Databricks using Python/Scala.

Below is my code snippet. I'm getting the below error. How can I create the table first if not exists in Databricks notebook using Python or Scala and then load the data?

If so, what functions do I need to use? Below gives me an error.

```
df1.write.format("snowflake").options(sfOptions).option("dbtable","TEST_TABLE")
         .mode(SaveMode.Append)
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: Without an error message, this question is missing a [mcve]. I will vote to close for now.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Scala code then your df write should look like this:

```
df.write
    .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
    .options(sfOptions)
    .option("dbtable", "t2")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save()
```

If you use Python code then your df write should look like this:

```
df.write
    .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
    .options(**sfOptions)
    .option("dbtable", "t2")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save()
```

where:

```
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
```

Observe there is a difference between the **options** on Scala vs Python.